# Remove 1px padding right linearlayout blank space

Tags: java, android

Hay. I am creating the layout in pure java. Code:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ============ FULLSCREEN

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // ============ LINEAR MAIN

    LinearLayout layPrincipal = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layFragP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layPrincipal.setLayoutParams(layFragP);
    layPrincipal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // ============ SET

    setContentView(layPrincipal);

    // ============ IMG

    ImageView imagemCurso = new ImageView(this);
    imagemCurso.setImageResource(R.drawable.intro);
    imagemCurso.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    layPrincipal.addView(imagemCurso);

}
```

}

There is a white line on the right side. It appears that the linearlayout has a right internal spacing of 1px. Look:

[image]

I already swapped the image for a textview, but the same problem occurs. I tried to set the padding to zero in the linearlayout, but without success. I tried to set gravity in the center, without success. I’m always using MATCH_PARENT. I tried Can someone help me? Grateful for the attention.

Comment: I tried your code with different image and it is working properly. Maybe your image itself has that 1px padding. Please try using different image and check this.

Comment: Please the App on a real device. I already test it and everything is ok. Sometimes emulator creates some unusual issues.

Comment: I will check on a real device and notify the result. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is issue in setAdjustViewBounds=true

Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Note: If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.

[For more Detail click hear](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean))

Comment: The minimum API for my project is 16. And the target is 30. Removing the "setAdjustViewBounds" from the activity the problem was also solved in the emulator and real device. Thank you very much.